# How to color/grey out individual RecyclerView rows (via link to SharedPreferences)

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm currently writing a major upgrade to my language teaching App, and wanted to use SharedPreferences in order to store user progress. Basically, a recyclerview displays a list of topics, which lead to exercises -complete 5 exercises, and the topic is finished.

At this point, I call saveProgress(), and store the topic number and an int representing completion (1) in sharedPreferences.

However, how and where in the recylclerView code should I call the check for a topic being completed? Currently in my bindData method of my ViewHolder inner class, I have:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("phraseprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //the number topic serves as the key name of the preference
        int completed = sp.getInt(Integer.toString(mTopic.topicRef), 0);
        if (completed ==1){
            //we check if exercise completed, if so, make view greyed out
            float alpha= 0.65f;
            nameTextView.setAlpha(alpha);
            nameTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
            itemView.setAlpha(alpha);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
        }
```

This doesnt seem to work however. Any tips would be appreciated!

EDIT: Added in SaveProgress() method below, note that "topic" in this context is a number from 0-xxx, at increments of 5 per topic (i.e. topic 0,5,10, with exercises 0-4,5-9,10-14, respectively)

```
 public void saveProgress(){

    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("phraseprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

    //we use 1  to represent completion instead of boolean because we can also sum these numbers
    //for a completion percentage if necessary
    editor.putInt(Integer.toString(topic), 1);
    editor.commit();
}
```

EDIT2: Solved by a mixture of trial and error and magic.
First, initialize the textViews in ViewHolder constructor.
Second, Fetch sharedPreferences in OnBindViewHolder
Third, call methods to change the textViews within onBindViewHolder, provided the shared Preference meets your conditions.

Thank you all

Comment: How do you store topics, can you share the object you save to UserPrefs?

Comment: Hi Boris, added to original message. Note that this is called at the end of completing 5 exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `RecyclerView` shouldn't know about `SharedPreferences` at all. You probably have a model class `Topic` which contains all the information about a topic. You can include your completion `int` in this class. Something like this.

```
class Topic {
    /* all topic data */
    private int completion;

    public int getCompletetion() {
        return compeletion;
    }

    public void setCompletion(int completion) {
        this.completion = completion;
    }

    public Topic(/*Other Topics fields*/) {

    }

    public Topic(/*Other Topic fields*/, int completion) {
        /* initialization of other fields */
        this.completion = completion;
    }
}
```

Then you can load and set a completion `int` for each `Topic` in your array (I mean `List` or whatever container you use). Something like this

```
List<Topic> topicsList = new ArrayList<>();
/* add your topics to the list from whatever source */
for (Topic topic : topicsList) {
    topicsList.setCompletion(loadCompletion(topic));
}
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(topicsList)
/* ... */
```

Now, in order to check completion `int` for a `Topic` in your data array in your `RecyclerView` you can just call `topic.getCompletion()`. It would look something like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Topic topic = topicsList.get(position);
    int completion = topic.getCompletion();
    switch (completion) {
        case '0':
            holder.modifyViewForCompletionZero();
            break;
        case '1':
            holder.modifyViewForCompletionOne();
            break;
        /* Call holder methods for other completion states */
    }
}
```

And your inner `ViewHolder` would contain methods for adjusting view for each state.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive reply. I think I will try and adapt what youre doing. However, I want to use Preferences due to the Data persistence aspect.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences, local database, file storage, or whatever you see fit. The point is that RecyclerView does not need to know where data, or parts of data, come from